# cropping white space around a large image

Tags: image, whitespace, crop

I am trying to crop white space around a large image. 2000px X 32000px. I tried convert trim but it failed, also tried mogrify and it failed too. I have tried to install the R magick library that came with additional errors and warnings. Additionally, I tried PIL but it did not install on my Python 2.7. Anyways is there a simple solution on clipping the surrounding white space of my image. Any help is deeply appreciated.
I have 100 images like this to trim.
Here is my convert command:

```
convert A1.png -fuzz 0% -trim +repage A_N.png'
```

Comment: Has your image got noise? Is it a scan? Did you try adding a large `-fuzz` factor?

Comment: My image is a black and white heatmap.png generated using image function of R. I do not think it has any noise, atleast to my knowledge.

Comment: Try `mogrify -fuzz 50% -trim image.png`

Comment: mogrify -fuzz 50% -trim A_N.png
mogrify: ../../magick/quantum.c:216: DestroyQuantumInfo: Assertion `quantum_info != (QuantumInfo *) NULL' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: With `convert` you specify input and output, with `mogrify` you just specify the input and it is modified *"in situ"* generally.

Comment: Equally `convert input.png -fuzz 50% -trim +repage output.png` should work.

Comment: Actually, I made a copy of A.png as A_N.png to use it in mogrify since it changes the input. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Your current `-fuzz 0%` requires every single border pixel to be identical down to the last bit before it can be trimmed. You better not be using JPEG or have a single grain of noise!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183214/discussion-between-mparida-and-mark-setchell).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution to my issue in R. I added this line par(mar=c(0,0,0,0)) before plot/image function and it did the trick and generated an image without any margins for me.
It may not be what I was asking here but it is a better solution than what I had in my mind of cropping the white space around an image after it was done. It is a simple solution and removes the issue of white margins before drawing the plot.
Thank you all for your suggestions and help. If you disagree with this solution please let me know and I will be happy to work on them.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I just wrote this image cropper:

```
# Load packages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import glob

# List all logo files
path = r"K:\Folder/"
files = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "*logo.png", recursive=True)]

# Loop!
for file in files:
    # Load image
    img=plt.imread(file,0)

    # Start from top down
    found_white_row = True
    row = 0
    while found_white_row:
        check = True
        for layer in range(img.shape[2]):
            check = ((img[row,:,layer] == 255).all()) & check
        if check:
            row += 1
            if row > img.shape[0]:
                found_white_row = False
        else: 
            found_white_row = False

    img = img[row:,:,:]

    # Start from bottom up
    found_white_row = True
    row = img.shape[0]-1
    while found_white_row:
        check = True
        for layer in range(img.shape[2]):
            check = ((img[row,:,layer] == 255).all()) & check
        if check:
            row -= 1
            if row > img.shape[0]:
                found_white_row = False
        else: 
            found_white_row = False
            row -= 1

    img = img[:row,:,:]

    # Start from left to right
    found_white_row = True
    col = 0
    while found_white_row:
        check = True
        for layer in range(img.shape[2]):
            check = ((img[:,col,layer] == 255).all()) & check
        if check:
            col += 1
            if col > img.shape[1]:
                found_white_row = False
        else: 
            found_white_row = False

    img = img[:,col:,:]

    # Start from right to left
    found_white_row = True
    col = img.shape[1]-1
    while found_white_row:
        check = True
        for layer in range(img.shape[2]):
            check = ((img[:,col,layer] == 255).all()) & check
        if check:
            col -= 1
            if col > img.shape[1]:
                found_white_row = False
        else: 
            found_white_row = False
            col -= 1

    img = img[:,:col,:]

    # Save image
    plt.imsave(file.replace('logo.png','logo_cropped.png'),img)
```